# ASP.Net Sorting a Gridview even after going to next page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi all I am having trouble with the sorting of my gridview. Let's say my gridview has 10 rows of data and 2 columns, Name and Age. Paging is set to 5 rows of data a page. When i click on Name, it is sorted correctly. However when i click on the next page, it becomes "unsorted" again. Help please! I have attached the event handlers below.

```
    protected void SearchResultGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["SearchDS"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("PESearh.aspx");
        DataTable SearchDT = ((DataSet)ViewState["SearchDS"]).Tables[0];

        string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;

        if (ViewState["SearchSort"] != null && ViewState["SearchSort"].ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            if (!ViewState["SearchSort"].ToString().Contains(sortExpression))
                GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
        }
        else
        {
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
        }

        if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
            sortExpression += " DESC";
            SearchDT.DefaultView.Sort = sortExpression;
        }
        else
        {
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
            sortExpression += " ASC";
            SearchDT.DefaultView.Sort = sortExpression;
        }
        ViewState["SearchSort"] = sortExpression;

        this.SearchResultGridView.DataSource = SearchDT;
        this.SearchResultGridView.DataBind();
    }
```

and for my pagechanging

```
    protected void SearchResultGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchResultGridView.DataSource = ViewState["SearchDS"];

        SearchResultGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        SearchResultGridView.DataBind();
    }
```

I need help so that the previous sorting also sorts the next page. Please help thanks!

Note: I do not want to sort the data before binding because I want the user to see the data first and then decide what to bind.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want the user to see the data first and then decide what to bind"? I don't understand why this stops you from setting the `DefaultView.Sort` like you did in `SearchResultGridView_Sorting`.

Comment: this code is copied from another developer on my team and i have no idea what he is doing. Anyway what i meant was, i do not want to sort it in the SQL code when binding the data. I want to have manual sorting by clicking the grid headers only

Comment: the trouble i have is with this line: string sortExpression = e.SortExpression; the e is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be saving the sort expression in `ViewState["SearchSort"]`. When you change the page index, the value should still remain in the `ViewState` variable, so you can just grab it and set it again with:

```
SearchDT.DefaultView.Sort = ViewState["SearchSort"].ToString();
```

Before sorting the data though, may want to get the `DataTable` first like so:

```
DataTable SearchDT = ((DataSet)ViewState["SearchDS"]).Tables[0];
```

Then, instead of assigning `ViewState["SearchDS"]` the `DataSource` of your `GridView` directly, you can use the new `DataTable` instead:

```
SearchResultGridView.DataSource = SearchDT;
```

Together, you have something like this:

```
protected void SearchResultGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable SearchDT = ((DataSet)ViewState["SearchDS"]).Tables[0];
    SearchDT.DefaultView.Sort = ViewState["SearchSort"].ToString();
    SearchResultGridView.DataSource = SearchDT;

    SearchResultGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    SearchResultGridView.DataBind();
}
```

To be safe though, you may want to check to may sure `ViewState["SearchSort"]` exists first before assigning (if not, then you can give it a default value).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am new to programming so yeah :D, anyway, i get an error. 4th line, ViewState["SearchSort"]  "Cannot implicity convert type 'Object' to 'String'. An explicit conversion exists. (Are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @Theone Oh I'm sorry, I forgot to use `ToString()`. I use Visual Basic more often, which does the conversion implicitly (so I often leave it out due to laziness). I've updated my answer with the correction. Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It can be compiled now but now it says.. Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.  `SearchDT.DefaultView.Sort = ViewState["SearchSort"].ToString();`